# Why the downloaded file numbers is not equal numbers of url's line in my log file?

Tags: python, scrapy

Platform: debian8 + python3.6 + scrapy 1.3.2.
Here is a simple scrapy script to download all the us stock quote.
Please to download the 7z file on webpage.

[all urls to be downloaded](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BpilWzmmMCRGQ0RF8xWWx3ZVU)

To extract it with 7z.

```
7z x urls.7z -o/home
```

The sample data  /home/urls.csv can be tested.
To save the below scrapy script as  /home/quote.py

```
import scrapy
import csv

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 3
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_SPIDER = 3
CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 100000
CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT = 36000
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10
RETRY_ENABLED = False
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_TIMES = 1
COOKIES_ENABLED = False

downloaded = open('/home/downloaded.csv','w')

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.timeout = 10

    name = "quote"
    allowed_domains = ["chart.yahoo.com"]
    csvfile = open('/home/urls.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rows = [row[0] for row in reader]
    start_urls = rows

    def parse(self, response):
        content = response.body
        target = response.url
        filename = target.split("=")[1]
        open('/home/data/'+filename+'.csv', 'wb').write(content)
        downloaded.write(target+"\n")
```

The last two lines in /home/quote.py is important,
**open('/home/data/'+filename+'.csv', 'wb').write(content)** to open a file and save the data into the file.
The following ,**downloaded.write(target+"\n")**,it is to write a log to describe which url was downloaded instantly.

To execute the spider with:

```
scrapy runspider  /home/quote.py
```

In my opinion the numbers--all downloaded files is equal to line numbers of url in /home/downloaded.csv.

```
ls  /home/data |wc -l
6012
wc /home/downloaded.csv
6124
```

Why two numbers here aren't equal?
Please to test on your plarform and tell me the two numbers.

Comment: Please share some of your console logs, especially the stats dict at the end. You will see counter for the different HTTP status codes that Scrapy's downloader gets back. Maybe some of your URLs get redirected or get a HTTP 404 back (and they will not get passed to your `parse` callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file 'urls.csv' there are repeated URL. For example https://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=JOBS, or https://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=JRJC.
The function open() with mode 'w' truncate the file if it already exists, then rewrite it. 
You can check it with something like:

```
    if not os.path.exists('/home/data/'+filename+'.csv'):
        open('/home/data/'+filename+'.csv', 'wb').write(content)
        downloaded.write(target+"\n")
    else:
        downloaded.write(target+" already written \n")
```